# Getting a null value when radio button is clicked for the first time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using DHTMLX which outputs the XML data into a table.

I have this code working but when the radio button is clicked for the first time it shows the row id as null. Second time onwards it works.

http://jsfiddle.net/19eggs/ep6JE/11/

```
    $(function() {
        $("input:radio").click(function() {
    var selectedId=mygrid.getSelectedRowId(); // DHTMLX method to get the row id, selects the row id eg: 110012178~01~01 and when the radio button is clicked for the first time it is null and second time it works
  //var selectedId=10; // As a test, if I use this then it works
    var clicked = [];
    $("input[type=radio]:checked").each(function() {

      clicked.push(selectedId+":"+this.value);
           });
      alert(clicked);

         });
         });
```

My post in the DHTMLX forum is here http://forum.dhtmlx.com/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=34634  without any replies ;o((

Comment: but no id is given to any of ur row

Comment: What about: `$("input:radio").change(function() {...});`

Comment: it is a defined by dhtmlx...http://docs.dhtmlx.com/doku.php?id=dhtmlxgrid:rows_manipulation

Comment: Nitin..Row Ids gets passed as an xml string <rows><row id="13000341~01~01"><cell> </cell>....Only when it is clicked first time it can't find the row id...Any idea ??

Comment: @A.Wolff, I tried that too, does not work.

Comment: Have you tried to change your line with `var selectedId = mygrid.getSelectedRowId();` to `var selectedId= $(this).parent("tr").attr('id')` ?

Comment: @Pavlo..it says undefined all the time..

Comment: It means that your `rows` are not defined with property `id`. So, how are you getting an `id` of the row if this property is not defined?

Comment: The row ids are set up in the xml string which DHTMLX shows as a grid.  To select the row id DHTMLX uses mygrid.getSelectedId(); to select the  row id. Maybe it would help to give a quick glance at http://docs.dhtmlx.com/doku.php?id=dhtmlxgrid:rows_manipulation and http://forum.dhtmlx.com/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=34634 (I have screenshots here ) and thanks for your help.